# How to configure Azure redis cache in vnet of azure kubenretes?

Tags: azure, docker, redis, kubernetes, vnet

I am deploying my application on which uses "Azure Redis Cache" Azure kubernetes where "aks-vnet-xxx" created by default so I wanted to put redis cache under same vnet but I am not able to do getting error
[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the issue caused by the Subnet you used contains the resource of Azure kubernetes.

When deploying an **Azure Redis Cache** to a Resource Manager VNet, the cache must be in a **dedicated subnet**.

For more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-premium-vnet#why-does-creating-a-redis-cache-fail-in-some-subnets-but-not-others).

> If you are deploying an Azure Redis Cache to a Resource Manager VNet, the cache must be in a dedicated subnet that contains no other resource type. If an attempt is made to deploy an Azure Redis Cache to a Resource Manager VNet subnet that contains other resources, the deployment fails. You must delete the existing resources inside the subnet before you can create a new Redis cache.